# change datetime format in python list

Tags: python, list, datetime, datetime-format, enumerate

I want to convert date time from str like `2008-1-12 00:00:00` to `20080112`, the `datetimes` from an excel column. My program is as follows:

```
def btk_datetime2cvh(table, title):
    datetimes = list(table[title])
    dmyhms_pattern = re.compile(r"^((?:19|20)\d\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s+(20|21|22|23|[0-1]\d:[0-5]\d:\[0-5]\d)$")

    for num, dt in enumerate(datetimes):
        try:
            year, month, day, time = dmyhms_pattern.findall(dt)[0]
            if int(month) < 10 and int(day) < 10:
                datetimes[num] = year + "0" + str(int(month)) + "0" + str(int(day))
            elif int(month) < 10 and int(day) > 10:
                datetimes[num] = year + "0" + str(int( month)) + day
            elif int(month) > 10 and int(day) < 10:
                datetimes[num] = year + month + "0" + str(int(day))
            elif int(month) > 10 and int(day) > 10:
                datetimes[num] = year + month + day
        except (ValueError,TypeError,IndexError):
            datetimes[num] = "!" + str(dt)

    table[title] = pd.Series(datetimes)
    return table
```

The result of program running was very strange, most values were successfully converted to 8-bit characters like `20121231`, but some of them were remained same:

```
2008-10-11 00:00:00
2009-10-24 00:00:00
20070529
20051211
20060818
2016-10-11 00:00:00
20160503
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170908
20170906
20170906
20170906
20170906
2015-10-13 00:00:00
20170908
```

At first, I thought it might be caused by the setting of Excel cell format. However, after verifying the output of the program, there is no problem in String splicing of the program, but it seems that the new string has not been successfully assigned to `datetimes[num]`. I really do not konw why? who can help me?

Comment: You just need `import datetime from datetime` and `datetime.strptime('2008-10-12 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y%m%d')`.

Comment: @accdias, This is definitely a good way to go.  I prefer the dateutil parser cause I always have it handy, but this is the native way to do it.  The only thing I don't like is the tinkering with the explicity date formats.  If you have different formats in the incoming date column you may get weird results.

Comment: @Kelvin, yeah but it seems OP has just one datetime format on that data, so I guess it is safe to use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as typo/can not reproduce, since it seems OP just forgot to check for greater/lower than OR equal.

Comment: A little self serving, but I'd leave it open for others who are new to Python and struggle with date conversion to be pointed in the direction of a cleaner library or built in functionality

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the defacto dateutil library. https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

You can simply do this:

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = '2008-1-12 00:00:00'
parser.parse(dt).strftime("%Y%m%d")

>>'20080112'
```

Frequently rolling your own can be really error prone and complex.

Comment: Beautiful way,  I've applied these to my code, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at each of the dates that failed to convert, you'll see a pattern:

```
2008-10-11 00:00:00
2009-10-24 00:00:00
2016-10-11 00:00:00
2015-10-13 00:00:00
```

All have a month value of `10`.

Now look at your conditions:

```
int(month) < 10 and int(day) < 10:
int(month) < 10 and int(day) > 10:
int(month) > 10 and int(day) < 10:
int(month) > 10 and int(day) > 10:
```

You never account for month or day being exactly 10. None of the conditions are true, so nothing is changed.

Either add an `else` case to handle these instances, or maybe change some `<` to `<=` to handle exactly 10.

Comment: Great! I'm too careless, Thank you!